# Output Stage Stability

Tags: bjt, output, power-amplifier, biasing, quiescent

I've been reading over amplifier output stage design and hoped someone might be able to advise if my circuit has any fundamental flaws - or if there are any tweaks I should make that would bring significant improvement?

Design:

- Constant Current source sufficient to drive 1W into a 4ohm load (~ 18mA)
- Vbe Multiplier to bias the push-pull emitter follower transistors
- Input signal of max 6Vpp

Observations:

- Output isn't overly distorted (No crossover distortion)
- Quiescent current (lowering R4 to 1.4k has reduced this significantly!)

In particular, is it sensible to be setting the DC output voltage via R11 or is there a better way?

[image]

Input/Output Signals:
[image: Input/Output Signals]

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you getting cross-over distortion with your push-pull config? There’s a few ways such as level shifting that can eliminate that

Comment: Not that I can see (added input/output signal screenshot) - seems OK

Comment: @Cdevelop What you have is still mostly behavioral, not realizable. But I can see some basic ideas that are worth having. You have a current source at the top, this feeds a VBE multiplier (which can be adjusted), and you are driving a useful place.

Comment: @Cdevelop Some thoughts, though: (1) that you are using a \$500\:\Omega\$ resistor to sink what may be left of the \$\approx 20\:\text{mA}\$ current source. And resistors don't actively sink current. Suppose all that current went through that resistor, then it would drop \$10\:\text{V}\$! But if the amplifier were to be quiescent, then the BJT bases wouldn't really need any base current since the load would be at zero volts and wouldn't have any current, itself. That's just one thing to consider. You don't use a resistor at the bottom to receive what's left over (if at all possible.)

Comment: @Cdevelop (2) You also have a single rail supply so the load can see, at most, about \$2\:\text{A}\$ peak. \$20\:\text{mA}\$ from your source may be enough (assuming \$\beta\gt 100\$) but then your VBE multiplier wouldn't have any left over for itself (if \$Q_2\$ were needing all that base current.) Which means the VBE multiplier would be out of steam, so to speak, and wouldn't do its job well.

Comment: @Cdevelop I've no idea how much current there is flowing through both BJTs in a quiescent state. What does the simulator say? What does it say if you modify the BJT models to conform to the vagaries of what you can actually buy and use? (Yes, this means you'll need to get rid of the idealized NPN and PNP models, which don't have any Early Effect, for example.) I'd love to see you use BJTs capable of 2 amps and see what they need for base current, too. There's no short circuit current limits or foldback. There's no NFB to self-correct for distortion (needed moreso at a later time, perhaps.)

Comment: @Cdevelop I can't answer this, *"In particular, is it sensible to be setting the DC output voltage via R11 or is there a better way?"*, because this is worse than all other workable ways so the answer is just "yes, there's a better way." Lots of them.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. My reference book largely deals with the dual supply scenario, and i was attempting to do similar with a single supply (rightly or wrongly as i don't have a dual power supply available). When using the dual supply it seems trivial to get the output voltage to sit mid rail, but with a single supply I'm not so sure. I also tried using a current sink in place of R11 but then "How to get the output voltage mid rail?"

Comment: @Cdevelop A single supply just means (1) a capacitor at the output; or, (2) a bridged arrangement. It also means some 'adjustments' to the global NFB that you should be also providing, once the full amplifier is designed and ready. But it's not difficult. It's just a slight mental adjustment and a few part differences. Not much, really. Yes, it should sit "mid-rail" if you have got things right. But without the global NFB, you really don't know. Keep in mind this is only "the final stage" of some larger system. You can't really treat it in isolation.

Comment: @Cdevelop A stage like this also probably needs additional BJTs and resistors to help improve beta and also to provide current limiting and/or current foldback in case if direct shorts at the output. (You can almost bank on some accidental screwdriver in the wrong place.) And that assumes you get there rest of it right. Which it isn't yet.